# jQuery : element inside another, check the second by clicking on the first one

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Sorry for this title impossible to understand.

I have this:

```
<a class="directory">
    Directory 1
    <a class="add">Add a file</a> //show/hide on mouseover
</a>
```

for:

[image]

I do a toggle when I click on the first `<a>` to view the files :

```
$('a.directory').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul:first').slideToggle('medium');
});
```

I add a file when I click on the second `<a>`.

How do I check that I just click on the first `<a>` to avoid opening the folder when I click on the second `<a>`?

I try this but doesn't work:

```
$('a.directory:not(.add)').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul:first').slideToggle('medium');
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more or show more code? Your first click event is finding ul elements but the structure at the beginning of your example has a elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the second `<a>` out of the first one, that is not valid HTML anyway. Then you can format using CSS to get the same effect stylistically.

```
<a class="directory">
     Directory 1
</a>
<a class="add">Add</a>
```

Your selectors should then work as you'd expect.

Answer (score 2):

Since your second link has class, you can use that to your benefit:

```
$('a.directory:not(.add)').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.className === 'add') return false;
    $(this).parent().find('ul:first').slideToggle('medium');
});
```

Notice that addition of:

```
if (e.target.className === 'add') return false;
```

This would get out of function when you clicked on second Add File link which is what you are looking for.

---

Also your current markup isn't valid anyway  . You need to try and fix that instead.

Comment: It blocks the execution of my other $('.add').click(). I will try to change my markup (although all the JS has been designed for this markup...).

Comment: @GG.: That is due to link inside link, you actually need to fix that.